# bower package I created is only installing the dependencies, none of the actual package files

Tags: bower, package

I created a bower package and registered it. Now, when I install it, the package only installs the dependencies.  It does not install any of the files associated with the package itself, just the dependencies. I have tried unregistering it and registering it again but nothing changed.

What is happening to my files and how do I make them install?

```
bower install angular-scalable-boilerplate
```

https://github.com/bartmelton/angular-scalable-boilerplate